# Отправить POST-запрос на сервер

Tags: javascript, html, android, post

Делаю регистрацию через мобильное приложение без доступа к API сайта. То есть, я отслеживаю, какой запрос отправляется через форму регистрации на сайте http://ru.oriflame.com/business-opportunity/become-consultant

Вот перехваченный POST-запрос:

```
00:24:44.168    7.960   3558    (15497) POST    (Cache) text/html   http://0s.oj2s2zltnbxxa.n5zgsztmmfwwkltdn5wq.cmle.ru/iframe/Consultant/Registration.aspx
```

HEADERS:

```
(Request-Line)  POST /iframe/Consultant/Registration.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host    0s.oj2s2zltnbxxa.n5zgsztmmfwwkltdn5wq.cmle.ru
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://0s.oj2s2zltnbxxa.n5zgsztmmfwwkltdn5wq.cmle.ru/iframe/Consultant/Registration.aspx
Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=egqn0l3dpcgt2g2aunqcoqcq; PND_ID=4-0a116275-50
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length  2960
```

POST Data:

```
ctl00_RadScriptManager1_TSM ;;System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en-US:fa6755fd-da1a-49d3-9eb4-1e473e780ecd:ea597d4b:b25378d2;Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.2.724.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en-US:cbcc33a2-4a25-4f6b-85e3-8e20bc385048:16e4e7cd:f7645509:24ee1bba:f46195d3:2003d0b8:88144a7a:1e771326:aa288e2d:258f1c72;
ctl00$cphContent$txtInputStep   0
ctl00$cphContent$hidQuickFormMode   1
ctl00$cphContent$txtEmail   crot@ya.ru
ctl00$cphContent$txtPasswd  fox123
ctl00$cphContent$txtLastName    ÐÑÑÐ¸ÐºÐ¾Ð²
ctl00$cphContent$txtFirstName   Ð ÐµÐ½Ð°Ñ ÐÐ²Ð°ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ
ctl00$cphContent$txtUniqueId    1212990990
ctl00$cphContent$dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbDay 1
ctl00_cphContent_dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbDay_ClientState 
ctl00$cphContent$dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbMonth   Ð¡ÐµÐ½ÑÑÐ±ÑÑ
ctl00_cphContent_dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbMonth_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbYear    1971
ctl00_cphContent_dtpBirthDateCmb_cmbYear_ClientState    
ctl00$cphContent$txtMobile  79253318091
ctl00$cphContent$cmbServiceCentre   ÐÐ¼ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑÑ
ctl00_cphContent_cmbServiceCentre_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$hidLastLevelPK    
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$cmbPostCode   400100
ctl00_cphContent_ctrlAddr_cmbPostCode_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$cmbAddress3   ÐÐ¼ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ Ñ-Ð½.
ctl00_cphContent_ctrlAddr_cmbAddress3_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$cmbCity   ÐÐ¼ÑÐº
ctl00_cphContent_ctrlAddr_cmbCity_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$cmbAddress1   Ð Ð¾Ð¿ÐµÑÐ¾ÑÐ°
ctl00_cphContent_ctrlAddr_cmbAddress1_ClientState   
ctl00$cphContent$ctrlAddr$txtAddress2   120, 44
ctl00$cphContent$txtReqSponsor  4742088
ctl00$cphContent$txtSponsorName  ÐÐ»ÑÐ³Ð° ÐÐ¸ÐºÑÐ¾ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð½Ð° ÐÐ¾Ð¿Ð¾Ð²Ð°
ctl00$cphContent$chkAgreement   on
ctl00$cphContent$chkAgreement2  on
ctl00$cphContent$btnNext    ÐÐ°ÑÐµÐ³Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¸ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÑÑÑ
__EVENTTARGET   
__EVENTARGUMENT 
__LASTFOCUS 
__VIEWSTATE 
__EVENTVALIDATION   /wEdABKvVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPib4VpAD8zPDCDCMPJTCy4rlWYdcU3cLSXeUtoWRKzmCfu9zKX/5mwtXSqPani3yZUaIp2ePB9M7LMNOV+Aki/rYfkKiBer37H+sjS4b/dBUeSjybfAblpdTRG8WIf4HGnR4JQOorQHmpJAKUIdXv38Nr5AuQdnIUloVTyMbctE59+CKJQ+GC7cyXuhsK/81ID1BE3XyvDRlQWjZPMlPfvtg79hkwhC7VhEfI+8xzkOwLKmnDfDyQeKQCFCBXk0k7z449enIRKIxey04fdejWozk5GhJ1xCfHtHfdGEqJ3zu1p+ie3qCZKyp1TyAyMOaZhwZS4zXvn+KsIIw1LALQDWKWeJyxfWW4LhJAYDV8g51gmzGo7MCbJt6u5mHuytPBqTbQkQ==
```

Вот код из разрабатываемого приложения под Android, откуда нужно произвести нормальную регистрацию(использована библиотека ion):

[Код под Андроид](http://pastecode.ru/eba4b/)

Вот ответ от сервера на мой запрос, отправленный из приложения через ion (поля, которые я заполнял для отправки в запросе, почему-то, пустые):

[image: Ответ от сервера на мой запрос]

Как корректно сформировать POST-запрос через ion, идентичный запросу от клиентской части сайте?

Comment: Где иероглифы в пост запросе от ион? Или когда в браузере отправляете?

Comment: И вопрос, кстати не озвучен

Comment: С иероглифами в ответе от сервера я разобрался. ответ приходил без указания кодировки UTF-8: <meta charset="utf-8" /> . Осталось корректно сформировать и передать POST-запрос.